# how to show json output in html format in react native

Tags: react-native, node-modules, jsonresponse

```
"description": "<ul class=\" list-paddingleft-2\" style=\"outline: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-align: center; width: 1106.55px;\"><li style=\"outline: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; list-style: none outside none;\"><div style=\"\"><span style=\"outline: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16.1px;\"><p class=\"MsoNoSpacing\" style=\"text-align: left; \"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\">Mini USB cable is a stylish, sturdy and contemporary way of charging. It is made up of high grade material and offers faster charging &amp; data transfer. The enticing design of this USB is its USP. It is stylish, portable and can even be carried in pocket. The compact design of the Mini USB cable doesn’t acquire much space and doesn’t tangle like the common lengthy cables. This cable has rugged and sturdy build which offers faster charging and effortless data transfer. This product comes with replacement warranty. You can replace the product if you come across any manufacturing defects within the warranty period. Order this product today and carry it in your pocket for charging your Smartphone&nbsp;</span>anywhere anytime.&nbsp;<span style=\"font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom: 3.95pt; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><b><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;\r\ncolor:#C00000;mso-ansi-language:EN-IN\"><br><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\nOther features</span></span></b><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0cm 0cm 3.95pt -18pt; text-align: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">Soft grip</span></span><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0cm 0cm 3.95pt -18pt; text-align: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">Long life span</span></span><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0cm 0cm 3.95pt -18pt; text-align: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">Fast charging&nbsp;</span></span><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0cm 0cm 3.95pt -18pt; text-align: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">Portable &amp; affordable</span></span><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom: 3.95pt; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><b><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(192, 0, 0);\"><br></span></b></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom: 3.95pt; text-align: justify; line-height: normal; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><b><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(192, 0, 0); font-size: 14px;\">Technical Specifications</span></b><br></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0cm 0cm 3.95pt -18pt; text-align: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">Charging speed: 2A</span></span><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0cm 0cm 3.95pt -18pt; text-align: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">Length: 200mm</span></span><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n\r\n</span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">\r\n\r\n</span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0cm 0cm 3.95pt -18pt; text-align: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;\"><span lang=\"EN-IN\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">Connector type: Micro USB&nbsp;</span></span><span style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><o:p></o:p></span></p></span></div></li></ul>",
```

This is my json response and now i want to show this response in my native App of android and i have used packages like html view and render html view and first it showed he error -"
fontfamily "arial, sans-serif" is not a system font and has not been loaded through font.loadasync in react native"
but by searching i found the solution but after this error now its pop up cannot add a child that doesn't have a yoga node to parent without a measure function!

## how should i show the json response in html and to show in native page  and in response it has images how to do this  i am stucked ?

this is my code

```
<Text>
 <HTML html={this.state.data.description} imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} ignoredStyles={["font-family", "letter-spacing"]}/>
  </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [react-native-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html)

Comment: still same and i have used render html package but still the error is same ?

Comment: the library will handle images itself.

Comment: if your problem is with escaped strings, then you can use ```unscape``` function if needed.

Comment: unscape? can u explain with example...!

Comment: ‍‍‍```<HTML html={unescape(this.state.data.description)} ...```

Comment: now its showing error that cannot add a child that doesn't have a yoga node to a parent without a measure function and now the data.description field is empty